# Mass email a form to be filled out

Tags: apex-email-service, massemailmessage

I'm trying to capture quotes from vendors into our org.  We have EE and we do not have Sites.com.

Scenario:
A Contact is marked Vendor Source.
Purchase Request object and line items from related list gets pulled and sends mass email as a form to be filled out.  The vendor fills out form and replies back.  At this point I would like the email to somehow, with very little effort, enter the data from the replies into salesforce.

I'm not looking for this to be done with an app. I need to be able to do this with what I have.

Edited:
Okay, so I decided to work with force.com sites.  I'm trying to build a VF page, but it's not coming out the way I wanted.
VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="PartsRequests" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Parts Request">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!purchaseRequest}" var="pr">
                <apex:column value="{!pr.name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Select Request">
                    <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!pr.Selected_Request__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class PartsRequests {
    public List<Purchasing_Quote__c> purchaseQuote {get;set;}
    public List<Purchase_Request_Line__c> requestLine {get;set;}
    public List<Purchase_Request__c> purchaseRequest {get;set;}

    public PartsRequests (){
        purchaseQuote = new List<Purchasing_Quote__c>();
        purchaseRequest = new List<Purchase_Request__c>();
        getTodaysRequest();
    }

    public void getTodaysRequest(){

        for(Purchase_Request__c request: [select id, Name from Purchase_Request__c]){
            request.Selected_Request__c = false;
            purchaseRequest.add(request);
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

In the VF page, I'm not getting a checkbox to display for the Select Request Column.  I was going to use that to display child records based on which Purchase Number is chosen, but I'm not seeing anything. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your email has a relatively easy to parse format, i.e. it's obvious where the data is for each question, then you should be able to achieve this using an Apex based email service.

That said, to make this relatively tolerant of discrepancies in the data would be very tricky. You say you don't have Site.com but do you have force.com sites available? Using that, or a page in a Chatter community would be the better way to deal with this.

If you do use a VisualForce page then you need to make sure that the sites public profile has access to all of the necessary objects and fields in order to be able to collect data.

If neither of those are an option I'd consider hosting the form elsewhere, with the backend making an API call to Salesforce to send the data through. It would be relatively trivial to setup such a form on Heroku using Node.js and have it send the data to Salesforce by means of an integration user (using the nForce username & password flow).

Comment: We do have force.com sites.  How would I use a page in the chatter community to do this?

Comment: If you've got sites then use that, but I believe for those that no longer have sites they can achieve similar functionality through communities. Communities might require people to be logged in as a Chatter Free user though, I've not looked into it in detail.

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: Ok, I've added a line which explains what you need to do - you need to edit the sites public profile (accessed via the sites config, *not* via user profiles) to ensure that the public profile has write access to the field. For future reference, this update should probably have been made into a new question as it means the answer makes little sense now!